# Elliptic function $f(z)=\frac{a_{-2}}{z^2}+a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots$ must be even

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb {C}$ be a nonconstant elliptic function such that $$f(z)=\frac{a_{-2}}{z^2}+a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots$$
>
> How to prove that $f(z)$ is even.

Notice that $f'(z)+f'(-z)$ is entire and elliptic therefore constant.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, that's an elliptic function *because* you say so, so let us assume it...yet I can't see how it *has to be* even if the coefficients of the odd powers of $\;z\;$ are non-zero...

Comment: @Timbuc I guess you'd need to prove that those coefficients are zero...

Comment: @dietervdf That's probably the problem.

Comment: @fe You say "notice..." etc. , but $\;f'(z)+f'(-z)\;$ has a power of $\;z^{-3}\;$ **unless** $\;a_{-2}=0\;$ , and then I wonder why would you give the power series for $\;f(z)\;$ beginning with this term!

Comment: @Timbuc those terms cancel out. $$\frac{-2a_{-2}}{z^3} + \frac{-2a_{-2}}{(-z)^3} = 0$$

Comment: @dietervdf Of course! When differentiating $\;f(-z)\;$ I forgot to multiply by $\;(-1)\;$ (chain rule). Thanks.

Comment: Can’t you use the same argument on $f(z)-f(-z)$? That’s essentially the odd part of (any) $f$, and isn’t it zero here?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $f(z) = \wp(z) + \wp'(z)/\wp(z)^2 = 1/z^2 - 2z + ...$

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer.

First note that if $\omega$ is any period for $z\mapsto f(z)$ then $\omega$ is also a period for $z\mapsto f(-z)$, because $$f(-(z+\omega)) = f(-z-\omega) = f(-z)$$
for all $z$. (The set of periods of $f$ is invariant under negation.)

Now, $f$ is even iff $f(-z) = f(z)$ iff $f(z) - f(-z) = 0$.
Since $f(z) - f(-z)$ is a difference of elliptic functions, it is itself elliptic, 
with power series expansion around the origin given by
$$f(z) -\!f(-z) = 2a_1 z + 2a_3 z^3 + 2a_5 z^5 + \dotsb.$$
At first I thought this would tell us $f(z) - f(-z)$ was entire, but 
this only says that $f(z) -\!f(-z)$ has no pole at the origin.
If we knew, say, that the pole-set of $f$ was invariant under negation, then we'd be done.

Supposing someone shows that $f(z)-\!f(-z)$ has no poles, then we'll know that $f(z) -\!f(-z)$ is a constant. Which constant? $0$, by continuity of the power series about the origin: $f(z)-\!f(-z) \to 0$.